# put div inline with even spaces

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to remake the google home page and I have done most of it except for the bottom of the google page were the most used apps are

[image]

that is what I want to get but when I use `inline block` I get

[image]

I looked all over google but I can't find one that works for background image.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class='mostUsedApps'>
  <div class='youtube rowCell'></div>
  <div class='facebook rowCell'></div>
  <div class='roblox rowCell'></div>
  <div class='Agar rowCell'></div>
  <div class='gmail rowCell'></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.youtube{
  background-image: url(youtube.png);
}

.facebook{
  background-image: url(facebook.png);
}

.roblox{
  background-image: url(roblox.png);
}

.Agar{
  background-image: url(Agar.png);
}

.gmail{
  background-image: url(gmail.png);
}

.trading{
  background-image: url(lernforex.png);
}

.trading1{
  background-image: url(lernforex.png);
}

.wordpress{
  background-image: url(wordpress.png);
}

.onlinegames{
  background-image: url(onlinegames.png);
}

.spredsheet{
  background-image: url(spredsheet.png);
}

.rowCell{
  width: 50px;
  height: 61px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any idea how I can reproduce the first image with `inline-block` or any other display? Any help is much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: I'd suggest flexbox position: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Flexbox should work, but not all browsers support it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp. A grid or bootstraps rows and columns could also work, and they are more widely supported.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: flex works it puts it inline but is there a way to make the spaces even and smaller

Comment: @LejaVaitkeviciute yeah but you have to reduce the size of your mostUsedApps container afterwards flex is using that space to place all elements equally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add a white space between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785299/add-a-white-space-between-divs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with flex, complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.mostUsedApps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```