# add a white space between divs

Tags: html, css, whitespace, spacing

I am remaking the Google Chrome home page, but I'm stuck on the part at the bottom of the page with the spaces. I can't get them perfect. Two of the icons don't aline.

Here is what I need compared to what i get

[image] 
[image]

At the sides the spaces are too small and in the middle they are too big.
If I can somehow make the spaces in the middle smaller and on the sides bigger then I can reproduce the first image

I tried
`justify-content: space-between;`
and
`justify-content: space-around;`
and
`justify-content: space-even;` 
they don't work

Here is my html

```
<div class='mostUsedApps'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='youtube rowCell'></div>
    <div class='facebook rowCell'></div>
    <div class='roblox rowCell'></div>
    <div class='Agar rowCell'></div>
    <div class='gmail rowCell'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
.youtube{
     background-image: url(youtube.png);
}
.facebook{
     background-image: url(facebook.png);
}

.roblox{
     background-image: url(roblox.png);
}

.Agar{
     background-image: url(Agar.png);
}

.gmail{
     background-image: url(gmail.png);
 }


.rowCell {
    width: 256px;
    height: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.row {
    padding: 120px 0 0 424px;
    height: 112px;
    width: 525px;
    display: flex;
}
```

any idea how i can do this, thanks (:

Comment: sorry that was a mistake when posting i will fix it

Comment: also it'd better if you create a fiddle / snippet reproducing the problem

Comment: Still need another closing div tag. What are the sizes of the images?

Comment: Where is closing tag for ```<div class='row'>``` ??

Comment: the sizes of the images are 48*48

Comment: another mistake i am really sorry

Comment: and i dont think i can create a  fiddle / snippet becase the images are from my computer can i ?

Comment: You can add placeholder images using https://placeimg.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make perfect center alignment between inline divs, you can use `text-align: center` on `display: inline-block` divs.

```css
div.container {
  text-align: center;
}

div.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon youtube"></div>
  <div class="icon facebook"></div>
  <div class="icon gmail"></div>
  <div class="icon site4"></div>
  <div class="icon site5"></div>
  <div class="icon site4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `justify-content: space-around;` css its working proper. you set fixed width of `row` div, I have set this `width:auto`.
Now you can use this code, I hope this will help you.

```css
.youtube{
     background-image: url(youtube.png);
}
.facebook{
     background-image: url(facebook.png);
}

.roblox{
     background-image: url(roblox.png);
}

.Agar{
     background-image: url(Agar.png);
}

.gmail{
     background-image: url(gmail.png);
 }


.rowCell {
    width: 61px;
    height: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: center;
}
.row {
    padding: 0;
    height: 112px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
    <div class='mostUsedApps'>
     <div class='row'>
        <div class='youtube rowCell'></div>
        <div class='facebook rowCell'></div>
        <div class='roblox rowCell'></div>
        <div class='Agar rowCell'></div>
        <div class='gmail rowCell'></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try it with  background-image because it dousent seem to work for me

Comment: one min , i am updating this.

Comment: Now use this css and check it. also remove `red` background css into your css

Comment: i did but it did not work

Comment: can you give me your icon image url? any icon

Comment: this is not icon image url.....

Comment: sorry this one chrome-search://ntpicon/size/24@1x/https://www.facebook.com/

Comment: but i did't get this image... by this path  , give me online path.

Answer (score 0):

```
.rowCell {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:50%;
    background-position:center;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```